# how we increase the size of the pyqt5 QCombobox dropDown button

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcombobox, qtstylesheets

I want to increase size of  the pyqt5 created QCombobox dropDown button.

```
        self.combo_box.setStyleSheet("QComboBox"
                                "{"
                                "border : 4px solid black"
                                "}"
                                "QComboBox::! on:pressed"
                                "{"
                                "border : 4px black;"
                                "border-style : dotted;"
                                "}")
```

Comment: [QComboBox::drop-down](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#drop-down-sub).

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for the comment but I did not get what you want to say.

Comment: It's a selector for the combo button which you can use to [apply stylesheet rules](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#sub-controls). I suggest you consult the voluminous [qt stylesheet documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#sub-controls) if you need more details.